# visualforce inputField on Lookup(User,Queue) data type

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I have a custom object on which i have a field named Owner which is of Data Type Lookup(User,Queue).
When i access this field on visualforce page like below just using standard controller, i am getting error :

```
<apex:inputField label="Owner" value="{!CustomObject__c.Owner}"/>
```

Expression value does not resolve to a field
Error is in expression '{!CustomObject__c.Owner}' in component  in page page1

How can this field be accessed in vf page.

EDIT :  Owner is a standard field on my custom object named CustomObject and i am using standard controller on apex:page tag using `<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c">`

SECOND EDIT :

Changing to

```
<apex:inputText label="Owner" value="{!CustomObject__c.Owner}"/>
```

works but i am not getting lookup UI functionality.

Comment: The Owner field is actually `OwnerId`, so do `{!CustomObject__c.OwnerId}`.

Comment: @ScottW Apologies .Looks like you recommened same solution also when i typed my answer as well.so i am ready to delete this and you can add your answer sir if you like :).I will upvote that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<apex:inputField label="Owner" value="{!CustomObject__c.OwnerId}"/>
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error:  Error: Unknown property 'CustomObject__cStandardController.CustomObject__r'.

Comment: Can you try now?